# Python is printing more than I want

Tags: python

Why is it that below code prints 'None' as well as what I tell it to write when no match is found?

```
def subStringMatchExact(target,key):
    list=[]
    for fsi in range (len(target)):
        if key==target[fsi:fsi+len(key)]:
            list=list+[fsi,]
            #return list
    if list!=[]:
        return list
    else:
        print 'no match found'

print subStringMatchExact("banana","x")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is a implicit `return None` at the end of every function. This means that when you don't return anything, as in the `else` block of your example, your function returns `None` anyway. So, `subStringMatchExact("banana","x")` returns `None` and this gets printed.

Answer (score 9):

Let's look at this.

```
print subStringMatchExact("banana","x")
```

What value is returned by `subStringMatchExact`("banana","x")?  Don't look at what it **does**.  Look at what it **returns**.  For a hint on what a function returns, read the `return` statements.  All of them.  If there is no value on a `return` or no `return`, it returns `None`.

What does `print` do with that value?

Comment: Hi All,

Tnx for the tip!

better get the basics right first :)

tnx again
Baba

Comment: @S.Lott: I believe it's short for 'thanx'

Comment: Which is itself short for the actual English word: thanks.  Itself a short form of "thank you".

Comment: @John Machin and @JUST MY correct OPINION: How do you know these things?  Why didn't @Baba use the actual English word?

Comment: @S.Lott: This is off-topic; you should ask two separate new questions in the meta forum. However here are brief answers: (1) `http://www.internetslang.com/TNX.asp` (2) I can't channel @Baba; maybe you can.

Comment: @John Machin: They aren't meta questions -- they're specific questions specifically addressed at @Baba.  I'm not sure why you answered, since you can't channel @Baba.  My point is this: folks shouldn't use non-words like "Tnx".  Rather than be argumentative, I felt it better to ask @Baba what "tnx" meant, hoping that they would take the hint.

Comment: Hi All,

I was not aware that abbreviations like tnx are unwelcome so let me rephrase: thanks all for your submissions and your answers to my questions. Much appreciated.

Baba

Answer (score 2):

Think about what happens in the `else` clause here.  In the `if` clause your function returns a value.  In the `else` clause, what does it return?

That's why you're getting the result you are.  The `print` statement is printing the return value of the function, no matter which branch of the `if` is taken.  If a function exits without explicitly returning a value, it returns `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you don't explicitly return a value from a function in Python, `None` is implicitly returned.
By printing the return value of the `subStringMatchExact` function even when no match is found, you get than `None`, since the `else` clause doesn't end the flow with a `return` statement.

Answer (score 1):

use **return 'no match found'** instead of **print 'no match found'**

```
def subStringMatchExact(target, key):
    if key in target:
        n_target  = len(target)
        n_key = len(key)
        return [n for n in xrange(n_target) if key == target[n:n + n_key]]   
    else:
        return 'no match found'
```

Comment: Or even "raise SomeError('no match found')"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
def subStringMatchExact(target,key):
    list=[]
    for fsi in range (len(target)):
        if key==target[fsi:fsi+len(key)]:
            list=list+[fsi,]
            #return list
    return list
```

This way you're always returning a list, and the code calling subStringMatchExact can worry about what to do with the empty list (i.e. print not found, throw error etc.)

Comment: -1 The last four lines of your answer can be replaced simply by `return list`

Comment: Replaced last four lines with "return list"

Answer (score 0):

You are using print statement to print whatever is returned by the function. Thus in the "else" case you need to return rather than print in the function.

The correct code is therefore:

```
def subStringMatchExact(target,key):
    list=[]
    for fsi in range (len(target)):
        if key==target[fsi:fsi+len(key)]:
            list=list+[fsi,]
            #return list
    if list!=[]:
        return list
    else:
        return 'no match found'

print subStringMatchExact("banana","x")
```